# PHP MySQL : How to add data written into PHP into Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

So ive got a little webserver going on with a phone-book.
You can click on "add a new member", but when you fill in everything from the web server and click on "save" the new row is not showing up in the show-phone-book file.
I translated it, but the files and comments and in german.

I don't think there is anything more needed than this file, adding new member.

When i execute it, i can fill everything in, click "save" , then it dies and i get to the error : Anfrage fehlgeschlagen.

```
<?php

if ( $_GET['aktion'] == "speichern" )
{
$Nachname     = $_GET['Nachname'];
$Vorname      = $_GET['Vorname'];
$Anrede       = $_GET['Anrede'];
$Geburtsdatum = $_GET['Geburtsdatum'];
$Telefonnummer= $_GET['Telefonnummer'];
$Email        = $_GET['Email'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO Adressbuch SET ";
$sql .= " Nachname          = '$Nachname', ";
$sql .= " Vorname           = '$Vorname', ";
$sql .= " Anrede            = '$Anrede', ";
$sql .= " Geburtsdatum      = '$Geburtsdatum', ";
$sql .= " Telefonnummer     = '$Telefonnummer',";
$sql .= " Email             = '$Email'";




require_once ('konfiguration.php');
$db_erg = mysqli_query($db_con, $sql)
    or die(" Anfrage fehlgeschlagen");

exit;
}
?>


<form name="" action="" method="GET" enctype="text/html">
<p>Bitte geben Sie die Informationen von Ihrem neuen Kontakt ein<br>
</p>
<p>Nachname:<br>
<input type="text" name="Nachname" value="" size="60">
</p>

<p>Vorname:<br>
<input type="text" name="Vorname" value="" size="60">
</p>

<p>Anrede:<br>
<input type="radio" name="Anrede" value="w"> Frau
<input type="radio" name="Anrede" value="m"> Herr
</p>

<p>Geburtsdatum (YYYY-MM-DD):<br>
<input type="date" name="Geburtsdatum" value="" size="10">
</p>

<p>Telefonnummer:<br>
<input type="text" name="Telefonnummer" value="" size="60">
</p>

<p>E-Mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="Email" value="" size="60">
</p>

<input type="hidden" name="aktion" value="speichern">

<input type="Submit" name="" value="speichern">
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe you try to check errors?

Comment: You should really have a look at http://bobby-tables.com - Your application runs at a really high risk of SQL injection and your database can be hacked in a few seconds. NEVER put userinputs directly in your query, use prepared statements instead. You can find really good examples of how to use them on the linked website.

Comment: yea sorry, error says : Field 'ID' doesn't have a default value . So I've got everything displayed in the adding a new user file, but theres also a ID field in the view that counts from 1-20 on the members automatically.

Comment: capture user input, sanitise and commit to db follow these steps in all cases

Comment: i capture the user input but can't make them go into my table "adressbuch".

Comment: Please see my answer. You are using the wrong syntax in your query

Comment: @PeterMeadley Read a manual please https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: @PeterMeadley insert set exist

Comment: So I've been told

Comment: so i think the problem is, that i have the "ID" column, but i don't insert it. How can i change it, since ID should run at itself with 1, 2, 3, 4. I don't want the user to input that.

Comment: @cyxcat can you please find yourself a tutorial and learn mysqli and then come back to SO [mysli insert Data](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp). it looks like you still need em

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile sorry i got everything on that page right. the only problem is that i want a user input to insert the table not just write it by myself into the php file , i know how to do that. ;)

Comment: @cyxcat After all changes, did you receive your expected result now.?

Comment: Problem solved by myself : I had a ID column that wasn't Auto_incremented. Solved by just changing that on phpmyadmin.

Comment: @cyxcat Thats good.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to help avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First things don't use `$_GET` rather use `$_POST` method.

Then use prepared statements to protect against sql injections.

```
<?php
require_once('konfiguration.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $Nachname      = $_POST['Nachname'];
    $Vorname       = $_POST['Vorname'];
    $Anrede        = $_POST['Anrede'];
    $Geburtsdatum  = $_POST['Geburtsdatum'];
    $Telefonnummer = $_POST['Telefonnummer'];
    $Email         = $_POST['Email'];


    $sql  = "INSERT INTO Adressbuch (Nachname,Vorname,Anrede,Geburtsdatum,Telefonnummer,Email) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?) ";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_con, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssss', $Nachname, $Vorname, $Anrede, $Geburtsdatum, $Telefonnummer, $Email);

    if (mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {

        echo "data inserted";
    } else {

        printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
    }

}
?>
<form name="" action="" method="POST" enctype="text/html">
<p>Bitte geben Sie die Informationen von Ihrem neuen Kontakt ein<br>
</p>
<p>Nachname:<br>
<input type="text" name="Nachname" value="" size="60">
</p>

<p>Vorname:<br>
<input type="text" name="Vorname" value="" size="60">
</p>

<p>Anrede:<br>
<input type="radio" name="Anrede" value="w"> Frau
<input type="radio" name="Anrede" value="m"> Herr
</p>

<p>Geburtsdatum (YYYY-MM-DD):<br>
<input type="date" name="Geburtsdatum" value="" size="10">
</p>

<p>Telefonnummer:<br>
<input type="text" name="Telefonnummer" value="" size="60">
</p>

<p>E-Mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="Email" value="" size="60">
</p>

<input type="hidden" name="aktion" value="speichern">

<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="speichern">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using following method.

```
mysqli_query($db_con,$sql) or mysqli_error($db_con);
```

Comment: it will be great, if you write some text to explain your code better.

Answer (score -2):

You are using an UPDATE query syntax for an INSERT statement.

Try the following:

```
INSERT INTO Adressbuch (Nachname, Vorname, ...) VALUES ('$Nachname', '$Vorname',...);
```

Comment: Where should i add that?

Comment: Instead of your $sql = "INSERT INTO Adressbuch SET ".. etc

Comment: After i input everything it says : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '012345','test@test.com')' at line 1

Comment: Is the column type for telephone number Varchar or some form of Integer?

Comment: Also what is the column type of Geburtsdatum

Comment: telephone & email varchar, birthdate is date